# Selenium node docker images NODE_MAX_SESSION and NODE_MAX_INSTANCES env variables

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose file from [selenium wiki](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Docker-Compose).

For chrome and firefox nodes there are `NODE_MAX_SESSION` and `NODE_MAX_INSTANCES` env variables.

Is my understanding correct - there is no difference between configuring NODE_MAX_SESSION or NODE_MAX_INSTANCES for chrome or firefox image as for example chrome node can only start chrome browser and firefox node only firefox browser.

Why do then there are two of them ?

Answer (score 1):

NODE_MAX_INSTANCES

NODE_MAX_SESSION

Both needs to be configured for ex :

NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=6  NODE_MAX_SESSION=3
runs a chrome node which can run 6 instances of chrome, and a max parallelization of 3

Hope that answers your question

Comment: This clears my confusion about these 2 terms. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the [official](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) docs tell, we need both, if you plan sets the maximum amount of tests that can run at the same time in a node, so:

> By default, each image will only allow one slot per container,...this can be configured via environment variables with the environment variable `NODE_MAX_INSTANCES`.
>   Don't forget to combine this with the environment variable `NODE_MAX_SESSION`